# RTCDataChannel's "bufferedamountlow" event not firing in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc

I'm working on a project that utilizes WebRTC for file transfers, recently someone reported [an issue](https://github.com/mat-sz/filedrop-web/issues/1) saying that transfers end prematurely for bigger files. I've found the problem, and my solution to that problem was to rely on the `bufferedamountlow` event to coordinate the sending of chunks. I've also stopped closing the connection when the sender thinks it's complete.

For some reason, though, in Safari that event does not fire.

Here is the relevant code:

```js
const connection = new RTCPeerConnection(rtcConfiguration);

const channel = connection.createDataChannel('sendDataChannel');
channel.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

channel.addEventListener('open', () => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    let offset = 0;

    const nextSlice = (currentOffset: number) => {
        // Do asynchronous thing with FileReader, that will result in
        // channel.send(buffer) getting called.
        // Also, offset gets increased by 16384 (the size of the buffer).
    };

    channel.bufferedAmountLowThreshold = 0;
    channel.addEventListener('bufferedamountlow', () => nextSlice(offset));

    nextSlice(0);
});
```

[The longer version of my code is available here.](https://github.com/mat-sz/filedrop-web/blob/c30963a5ee6fcc523002c61534dcac5271622e7d/src/sagas/transferSendFile.ts#L25)

While researching the issue, I've realized that on Safari, my `connection.stcp` is undefined. (Since I've switched to `connection.sctp.maxMessageSize` instead of `16384` for my buffer size.) I would assume the problem is related to that.

What could be the cause for this problem? Let me add that on Chrome and Firefox everything works just fine without any issues whatsoever.

The `bufferedamountlow` event is not required for the proper function of my code, I would like for it to work, though, to get more precise estimates of current progress and speed on the sending end of the file transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it comes to me that Safari has issues with `0` as a value for the bufferedAmountLowThreshold property.

When set to a non-zero value, the code functions properly.

Checking the bufferedAmount inside of the nextSlice function also increases the speed at which the chunks are being sent:

```
const bufferSize = connection.sctp?.maxMessageSize || 65535;

channel.addEventListener('open', () => {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  let offset = 0;

  const nextSlice = (currentOffset: number) => {
    const slice = file.slice(offset, currentOffset + bufferSize);
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(slice);
  };

  fileReader.addEventListener('load', e => {
    const buffer = e.target.result as ArrayBuffer;

    try {
      channel.send(buffer);
    } catch {
      // Deal with failure...
    }

    offset += buffer.byteLength;

    if (channel.bufferedAmount < bufferSize / 2) {
      nextSlice(offset);
    }
  });

  channel.bufferedAmountLowThreshold = bufferSize / 2;
  channel.addEventListener('bufferedamountlow', () => nextSlice(offset));

  nextSlice(0);
});
```